# Can't reference UnityEngine.Windows.Speech

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the speech recognition functionality in Unity, but when I try to bring it it, Visual Studio isn't recognizing it.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
using System.Linq;



public class VoiceRecog : MonoBehaviour {

private KeywordRecognizer m_Recognizer;

public KeywordRecognizer keywordRecognizer;
protected Dictionary<string, System.Action> keywords = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>();

void Start() {
    Debug.Log("In the Start() of VoiceRecog");
    keywords.Add("go", () =>
        {
            GoCalled();
        });
    keywordRecognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords.Keys.ToArray());
    keywordRecognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += KeywordRecognizerOnPhraseRecognized;
}

void KeywordRecognizerOnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args) {
    Debug.Log("in 2nd function");
    System.Action keywordAction;

    if (keywords.TryGetValue(args.text, out keywordAction)) {
        keywordAction.Invoke();
    } 
} 

void GoCalled() {
    Debug.Log("You just Said Go.");

}
```

}

Unity isn't taking the KeyWordRecognizer type. I think because it's not bringing in UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.

Any ideas about why unityengine isn't being brought in?

Comment: Have you referenced the right assembly (not just added `using`)?

Answer (score 0):

To use `KeyWordRecognizer`, you must include `UnityEngine.Windows.Speech` at the top. You did this but `KeyWordRecognizer` is not still recognized.

The possible problem is that you are using older version of Unity. You must have Unity 5.4.0 and above in other to use `KeyWordRecognizer`.

[*Unity 5.4.0 Release Note*](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.4.0):

> Windows: Added speech recognition APIs under
>   UnityEngine.Windows.Speech. These APIs are supported on all

Also, it is *now* very easy to find out which version of Unity an API was added. This is a reference for you next time you encounter this problem.

Simply search and find the API then keep bringing the version number down until your current Unity version. The number changes by 10 like 550,540,530....

**Available**:

[image]

**Not Available**:

[image]